# Why this XPathExpression 'div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard"]' is not working?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I am developing a crawler with indeed.com. When I implement the xpath finding the path didn't work. Here is my expression tested in the chrome developer console. The result only returns an empty list.

```
$x('div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard"]')
```

And here is the original HTML code.

[I want to crawl the things inside the clickcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFfPK.png)

I am confused about how to fix this problem

Comment: @kjhughes Is there a way to copy the collapsed HTML? The original HTML is too much to copy.

Comment: You're expected to reduce the code/markup to a [mcve] that illustrates the problem concisely.  This should be in the body of your question so that this Q/A can benefit future readers even if the link changes or goes dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the following XPath in Scrapy to output the desired list of elements (remove the `clickard` part) :

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result"]').getall()
```

Always check what Scrapy returns to you (HTML code in `response`) before applying your XPath expression.

Output for the following [link](https://www.indeed.fr/jobs?q=boulanger&l=) : `18` elements.

In the JS console of your browser you have to input :

```
$x("//div[@class='jobsearch-SerpJobCard unifiedRow row result clickcard']")
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot "//". I feel guilty to ask a stupid question.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the best answer if your problem is solved.:)

Comment: May I ask why should I remove "clickcard"?  I thought it is just a part of the string?

Comment: `Clickard` is absent from the downloaded page returned by Scrapy. Downloaded pages are not exactly the same than the displayed (rendered) pages in your browser.